# What does Hinduism say about Transgenders?

Tags: sex, transgender

Some people who are born as biological males , consider themselves to be a woman.
Similarly is the case with some women.

What does Hinduism say about such people ?

Should they be considered as gender which they identify with or with their biological genders ?

Comment: One suggestion: please post question only if you don't find similar questions on this site. Use "search" box option before posting any questions. I think there are many questions on this topic posted already.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Transgenderism and Homosexuality both are different things.

Comment: @river then your tag is incorrect. You should use right tags when posting questions. Also there are multiple questions on transgenders too. Just search and you'll find it.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Transgenderism is related to homosexuality but not the same. 
I don't find any question on transgenders. You can see the right panel. No question with "Trans" is appearing.

Comment: The duplicate is about homosexuality; that question explicitly states that they're not asking about transgenderism. The only other question on the site that's relevant is this one https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49857/what-do-scriptures-say-about-transgenders, and that one has no answers.

Comment: @Heartspring thanks. Yes that question is relevant. Either way this question is good for closing. However we should avoid asking same question again and again. Rather if we seek answer alone, we should edit or offer bounty to the existing question in order to draw attention of other users. This is the correct way.